# Is this a bed bug nymph?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]hello ,

I want to know if this is a bed bug nymph or it's just an another insect? I got an issue with bed bugs few days ago in a hotel during a travel to Prague. Once home (in Germany), I washed all I had taken with me (a backpack with some clothes) under high temperature > 150 Fahrenheit. So I was confused when I found this bug on my arm today. I'll point out that I was under a tree and there were many tiny insects just a few minutes before I found this one. ﻿ This specimen was ~1 mm in length.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide your location and an approximate size of your insect. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I'm actually in Germany and the insect size is about 1 mm.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this angle and the way the legs are positioned. Could be a bedbug nymph or a booklouse. The biggest visual difference is that a booklouse has a narrower neck; bedbugs have barely any neck. If you can get a look from a different angle and compare to some photos of booklice you'll be able to tell.